# Passing nested quoted variable into a remote ssh command

Tags: bash, ssh

I have the following script which sets the hostname for a remote host.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -T user@$1 << \EOF1
        sudo sh -c "echo "hostname=\"$1\"" >> /etc/rc.conf"
        sudo /etc/rc.d/hostname start
EOF1
```

When I run `./filename.sh host`, the hostname isn't populated. How do I pass a variable to remote execution commands?

Comment: `\EOF` causes `$1` to not be expanded in the here-doc. Is that what you wanted to do?

Comment: Nope. I actually added \EOF for a nested heredoc and forgot to remove it. You found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter expansion is performed in here-docs if the delimiter is entirely unquoted.

So in the here-doc for

```
ssh -T user@$1 << \EOF1
```

where the `E` in the delimiter is quoted, `$1` is not expanded: it is passed as `$1` to ssh and then to `sh`. On the remote execution, `$1` is replaced with the empty string, since there are no positional arguments.

If you don't quote the `E`, the `$1` will be expanded in the here-doc:

```
ssh -T user@$1 << EOF1
```

Answer (score 1):

I might write this as

```
printf 'hostname="%s"\n' "$1" | ssh -T user@"$1" <<\EOF1
  sudo tee -a /etc/rc.conf > /dev/null
  sudo /etc/rc.d/hostname start
EOF1
```

to simplify the quoting. `ssh` passes its standard input to the remote shell, from which `tee` inherits *its* standard input. Now you can safely quote the here document, because it is independent of the value of `$1`.

It's also safer, as now `$1` is no longer an opening for code injection. It's just data input to the script, rather than code that is *part* of the script.